# UUID generator problem

Tags: c++, c, linux, uuid

I have a uuid class that is part of a portable library that gets initialized with the following piece of code.  It works fine under windows, but under linux it's
not generating UUID's correctly.

```
uint32 data[4];
data[0] = rng.Get();
data[1] = rng.Get();
data[2] = rng.Get();
data[3] = rng.Get();

data[1] = (data[1] & 0xffffff0f) | 0x40;
data[2] = (data[2] & 0x7fffffff) | 0x40000000;

printf("12345678901234567890123456789012\n");   
memcpy(uuid, data, 16);


for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%04X", data[i]);
printf("\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02X", uuid[i]);
printf("\n");
```

The printf statements are me debugging it.

But, the numbers are messed up.
Why are the bottom 4 bytes empty?
And why is the first uuid printed, different from the last?

The platorm is 64bt linux on x86.  This will always be run on x86 small endian architecture.

e.g. sample output

```
1st run
12345678901234567890123456789012
B6D2ADAF46CF624A581187F3670BBEE0
AFADD2B6D6E792FB4A62CF4600000000  // why is this different from the previous no?. also the last 4 bytes not set???


2nd run
12345678901234567890123456789012
96D6D234D5602743548FD812A0D96818
34D2D6965B65F32F432760D500000000 // same problem as earlier
```

Something is going haywire with the conversion.

This has now been solved.  I don't care about endianess. The bytes are random anyway!

Comment: What is the definition of `uint32` and what type is `uuid`? Also in the first debugging snippet you print a minimum of 4*4 chars; in the 2nd you print a minimum of 16*2 chars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that the `%X` specifier is expecting an `int`-sized input to be passed, while you seem to be passing it an `unsigned char` (isn't that what `uuid[i]` is?).

Try doing this and see if it helps:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    int temp = uuid[i];
    printf("%02X", temp);
}
printf("\n");
```

### Update - New theory

OK, I looked at it more carefully after reading Matthew's answer.

The issue is `memcpy` along with the (unknown) type of `uuid`. You copy the `uint`s over `uuid`. The first 4 bytes of `uuid` are the little-endian representation of `data[0]`, as should be expected.

Now one theory that could explain the rest is that `uint32` is actually 8 bytes long instead of 4, so when you copy the first 16 bytes of `data` onto `uuid` we see in order:

- 4 LSB of `data[0]`, little endian
- 4 MSB of `data[0]` (junk)
- 4 LSB of `data[1]`, little endian
- 4 MSB of `data[1]` (junk, for some reason all zeroes)
- And nothing of `data[2]` and `data[3]`.

So what is `sizeof(uint32)` equal to?

Comment: I should be converting 4x 4 byte random int's to 16 bytes.

Comment: @MattH: So what is `uuid`? It's got to be something with that.

Comment: Awesome. it was the size of uint32. Turns out it's 8 bytes instead of the expected 4! declared as long unsigned int instead of just unsigned int.

Comment: @MattH: Nice! I was going out on a limb there, writing that `uint32` is 64 bits :)

Comment: Of course. uint32 is guaranteed to be at least 32 bits, but not necessarily exactly 32 bits.

Comment: @MatthewD: To tell the truth, without reading any docs, just by reading the code, I would certainly expect it to be *exactly* 32 bits. That's on general principle, of course.

Comment: With C99, `#include <stdint.h>` and use `uint32_t`, `uint64_t` for exact width types -- or `uint_least32_t`, `uint_least64_t` for minimum width types

Comment: thanks pmg for that hint.  The way the types.h header was defined in my library sources it would have used the correct size under windows but the broken size under linux.

Comment: By the way, data is an array of unsigned char.

Comment: @pmg: Yes, you're right! `uint32` isn't even a standard type. It's probably a user-defined type left-over from pre-C99 code that was designed to run on a 32bit system.

Answer (score 1):

The first 4 bytes of `data` and `uuid` are the same, but in reversed order - looks like an endianness issue.

- This is due to the printf printing each uint32 as one block, but the (unsigned?) chars in memory order.

The 2nd 4 bytes of `data` and the 3rd 4 bytes of `uuid` are also the same, but reversed. Similar issue.

Solve these two issues and the rest will probably fall into place.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for debugging instead

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    printf("%04X ", data[i]);
printf("\n");

for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++)
    printf("%02X ", uuid[i]);
printf("\n");
```

I just added a space after the 'X's.

Answer (score 0):

Two things are happening here:

1. the endian problem
2. you are on a 64 bit machine, so the compiler aligns the (32bit)ints to the native word

In general, you cannot assume how the compiler lays things out in memory.
You have to do it the old fashioned way: uuid[0] = data[0] >> 24 & 0xFF

Answer (score 0):

uint32 is not 32 bits in 64Bit OS, but 64 bits. I saw it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/Carbon64BitGuide/PortingTo64Bit/PortingTo64Bit.html) but I think it's true on all 64bit systems.

Comment: didn't you say the size definition was the problem?

Comment: Yep, that was the issue. The uint32 was came out at 8 bytes instead of the expected 4.  I was able to narrow it to a types header file that had an incorrect definition.  You say that uint32 is not 32 bits on a 64bit OS, but on my platform it now is and I am running 64 bit linux. i.e. unsigned int = 32 bits. long unsigned int = 64.  I changed to the 1st definition for uint32

Comment: And the problem still exists? Unless there is alignment of 64bit, you should stay only with the issue of endianess.