# In C, if you have a struct consisting of an int pointer and an int variable itself, how many bytes is it?

Tags: c, struct

For example:

```
struct myCar{
   int price;
   int *uniqueID;
};
```

In C, an int has 4 bytes. I'm assuming a pointer also occupies 4 bytes as well? Therefore, 8 bytes total?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the bit size of long on 64-bit Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/384502/what-is-the-bit-size-of-long-on-64-bit-windows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find out:

```
printf("Size of my struct is: %zu\n", sizeof(struct myCar));
```

The size of a pointer is platform dependent. For that matter, the size of an `int` is platform dependent. Could be 8 bytes for either if you're on a 64bit machine.

Comment: The size of the `int` is compiler dependent, too.

Comment: Also, the padding on the struct could force it to a value other than these.

Answer (score 1):

For i386, yes.

However, that's a big assumption. The size of something is what it is. Use sizeof(struct myCar) to get the answer for your architecture.

my sizeof(int) = 8.

Answer (score 1):

This is not accurate. the size of int may vary between different systems. It is the "natural word size" of the system. So usually it will be 32 bits in 32Bit systems, but 64Bit in 64Bit systems (and in older systems int is sometimes 16bit). Also the size of the pointer is usually the size of int.

Comment: The size of an `int` is not necessarily 64bit on 64bit systems- Visual Studio still has it as 32bit.

Comment: +1 @DeadMG, same with clang and gcc on 64-bit OS X.  @MByD, There's also no reason for a pointer and `int` to be the same size.

Comment: @DeadMG - You are right of course. Also the size of uint32 is not necessarily 32 bits :) -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5427037/uuid-generator-problem/5427216#5427216

Comment: An int is 32 bits on x86-64 because AMD decided that was the "natural word size" and the choice that results in the smallest machine code for the average program.

Answer (score 0):

In C, an `int` has `sizeof(int)` bytes. Likewise, a pointer to int has `sizeof(int *)` bytes. The actual size depends on the host environment and the compiler being used.

Likewise, your struct has `sizeof(struct myCar)` bytes, being at least as many as the sum of its elements. However, due to alignment issues, the struct may actually be larger.

So, never make any assumptions about the size of a data type (except `char`, which is guaranteed to be one byte). Rather use sizeof where appropriate.

On a sidenote, you also don't know the size of a single byte until you examine `CHAR_BIT` in `<limits.h>`.